# Asp.Net Lockups on Host Environment

Tags: c#, asp.net

Technology: Asp.Net 4.5

Type: MasterPage Application (Transaction/Items/Configurator)

We are in Load Test Phase.

The application locks up when there is more than one user using the application on the hosting environment (M6.Net). The application uses session variables to store datatables. Also, almost all the pages have insert, update, and delete statements to sql tables in the code behind. I have Option Strict turned on. I'm trying to figure out if its an SQL Server issue, memory issue, or something else. Once one user gets locked up, the rest get locked up and eventually goes to custom_error page but there is no error exception message. Has anyone experienced this issue and what is a good way to trouble shoot?

Would Glimpse be able to detect the issues? I have no experience with it.

Note: I did not post any code because I am at a loss as to what code I should post.

Comment: Can you recreate the issue locally, on your development machine, say by opening 2 browsers? If the debugger is attached and you hit pause, you will be able to see where in the call stack the app is dead locked. I'm going to guess it has something to do with the sql database and transactions. There really isn't enough info here to suggest anything.

Comment: Also, what was wrong with the answer you got with an almost identical question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23687848/asp-net-application-randomly-locks-up-with-multiple-users

Comment: It was his own answer @MatthewMartin

Comment: Yes, my previous answer to the previous post took care of some of the problem, but apparently not all of it. I will try 2 browser's on local. @MatthewMartin

Comment: @MatthewMartin So far I have tested locally with 3 browsers running simultaneously for over 30 minutes with no lockups or issues. My web.config was also pointing to the host database.

Comment: You are doing things in those 3 browsers, right? ASP.NET (and all web apps) are stateless. So if you, say, load up the home page 3 times, the server isn't doing anything. Except holding those datasets in memory. By the way, if you put enough datasets into memory, the app pool will recycle. That will make it seem like your session expired and depending on how the app deals with missing session values you'll get unexpected results.

Comment: Also, turn off custom errors so you can get the real error message. You don't get to the error page unless there is some Exception.

Comment: @MatthewMartin Yup, I have been loading all the pages many times along with many page postbacks as well. All 3 browsers operating correctly. turned off custom errors, still working good. I deployed the app on our Web Test Server (with iis default settings), multiple browsers working without any errors. A large dataset is loaded in the configurator page which is stored InProc Session variable. Not sure if this is a problem on external host server (M6.net) I need to do more investigating or scale down the app piece by piece until problem is found. More ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you run the website locally, you might want to monitor memory usage. VS Developer Web Server will use arbitrary large quantities of memory, IIS won't. Also you might want to count rows in those DataSets-- 1-10 rows are not likely a big deal unless there are blobs in there, but I remember a real life situation where 4000 rows reliably cause out of memory errors (this was iis 6 and asp.net 2, the threshold is probably different now)

Comment: And I'm still stuck on why you weren't able to capture the original error. You might want to consider installing some sort of error logger, like Elmah: https://code.google.com/p/elmah/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application was running out of memory. I didn't realize the provider account I was writing the app for only had 32MB of memory. So when several users were on and the memory peeked, the app pool would recycle wiping out the session variables and that was causing the errors.

We tested the application on another web server with a large amount of memory and the application worked as intended without any issues. We will be moving to a cloud environment with a significant amount of memory which will allow 500 - 1000 simultaneous users. During this troubleshooting process I did find some memory leaks and fixed those. I will be testing the session variables for values on postbacks to make sure the app pool didn't recycle as well.

@MatthewMartin - Thanks for all your input.